# Counting unique elements in text file

Tags: text-processing, cut

I have a text file containing tweets by users where:

```
470192   anneJackson    Apple's new iPhone is a no go for me
470193   trex90         For something so expensive, I'll go for Android anyway 
470194   anneJackson    What an outrageous pricing!
```

where the first column denotes an ID, followed by the username and user's tweet. What i want to do now is to write a command to count the number of tweets by each unique user which gives me something like:

```
anneJackson   2
trex          1
```

I tried something like:

```
cut -f 2 Twitter_Data_1 | sort | uniq -c
```

but it doesn't feel right as I'm only using the user column not including the tweet.

Comment: What is the delimiter of your text file? Is it one tab or some spaces?

Comment: @glennjackman it would be tabs

Answer (score 4):

It's a good job for **awk**:

```
awk '{ a[$2]++ }END{ for(i in a) printf "%-15s%s\n",i,a[i] }' Twitter_Data_1
```

- `a[$2]++` - increment occurrences of each unique *username* (presented by the 2nd field value `$2`)

The output:

```
trex90         1
anneJackson    2
```

Comment: yes awk works fine but I didn't really learn it in depth for now. If we were using cut, how would i modify the code above to yield the same result?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your file has fixed width columns and the spaces between columns are blanks and not tabs,

```
cut -c 10-24 Twitter_Data_1 | sort | uniq -c
```

This will give you

```
      2 anneJackson    
      1 trex90
```

You don't need to include the tweet in your command as every line represents a tweet.